# Can't cancel the restart/shut down dialog box in Gnome

Tags: gnome, shutdown, restart

When I click on the "Restart..." or "Shut Down..." options of the Gnome panel, a box dialog appears in order to confirm whether I really want to "Accept" or "Cancel" the process (as expected).

However, when I press "Cancel" (or even if I simply press the "x" button to close the dialog), the process continues as if I had pressed "Accept."

I have Ubuntu 14.04, and Gnome 3.10.4.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2271388 (no solution though)

Comment: Thanks. Apparently this bug is fixed in Ubuntu 14.10. I guess I will have to wait until the next LTS release comes out...